# Want to block all posts of spacific author via robots.txt file

Tags: robots.txt

I am using WordPress, and we never show the author name in the URL of the article URL is domain.com/this-is-a-great-post
but the author's name is visible in the article only the URL is without author's name what do I need to do if I want to block all posts of a specific author via the robots.txt file

Answer (score 0):

You should use [the `robots_txt` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/robots_txt/) to exclude all of the URLs of posts written by specified author (untested):

```php
add_filter( 'robots_txt', static function ( $output ) {
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'author' => 3,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'no_found_rows' => true,
        'fields' => 'ids',
    ) );

    if ( ! $query->have_posts() ) {
        return $output;
    }

    $siteurl = untrailingslashit( get_site_url() );

    foreach ( $query->posts as $post ) {
        $url     = str_replace( $siteurl, '', get_permalink( $post ) );
        $output .= sprintf( 'Disallow: %s\$%s', $url, PHP_EOL );
    }

    return $output;
} );
```